# Windows form - Custom User control in Panel

Tags: windows

I have a panel control that loads a user control inside it. Panel has auto scroll property set to true. A user can select an option from the menu and based on which Panel is cleared and new user control is loaded. This user control contains an Infragistics grid. The length of the infragistic grid varies based on the number of rows so at times it goes out of the height of the panel. 
The problem I have been facing is that once user scrolls down using panel scrolls and then chooses another option from menu that loads new User control with grid in it, the size of the grid cuts down. The scroll position of the panel is set to the start however, the upper part of the UC (having grid inside it) is lost. I cannot scroll up to see it as well.

I have been trying to figure it out based on how a control is loaded and drawn in the panel along with the scrolling of the panel to come to some understanding, but have been unsuccessful so far. Pls help.

Comment: Location property in DisplayRectangle property of Panel changes to some negative value for Y axis, which is displacement for vertical scroll. But when i choose to load new user control, this value is reset to 0. It was -816 when i scrolled down in one control. Then selected new value from menu and cleared the panel, this value changes to 0

Comment: Pretty unclear, but you probably have to adjust the control's Location by the panel's AutoScrollPosition.

Comment: Thanks Hans for your reply. I now try to be more clear. We have a form with a Panel in which we load a user control (UC). UC has infragistics grid. The height of this grid varies, and so is the height of the UC. We have a menu which gives user options. When user selects any option, Panel is cleared and a new UC is created. If user scrolls down the panel and then choose another option to load UC again, the UC is cut from the top to the point where until panel was scrolled.

Comment: Adding more that i found out, height of the user control is 3000, so the panel display rectangle is set to 3000. Then i scroll down, let's say, Y = -1000, the height of display rectange now is 2000. If user now decides to choose another otion which loads UC of height 1500, Panel loads only area falling under 1000-1500 height of this control. First 1000 is already cut down and cannot be scrolled up. I hope this helps to make it clearer